# Is there a way to override sensor data?

Tags: android, android-sensors

I plan to make an app that send data sensors and another that receive them. The next step is that received data has to be used for the phone (replace/override internal sensors data with received one), a basic usage of this would be to deport all sensors.
Of course, the problem is the receiver part, as I would like to use received data sensors on any other app (games, Google Maps, Camera feed ...).

I found two options that I think are not practical :

- Modifying the kernel to add a driver to a virtual sensors that I could add data so that any app will read from this virtual sensor. (I don't know if this is feasible)
- Use XPOSED as I found a VirtualSensor project by Frazew (https://github.com/Frazew/VirtualSensor/blob/master/app/src/main/java/fr/frazew/virtualgyroscope/XposedMod.java) so that any calls to registerListener is redirected to a custom and modified methods implementation.

But both would need systems modifications and is unpractical for publishing the app (either flash the system or install XPosed on the device). 
Thanks for any reply to any another methods or feasability issues I may encounter !

Comment: Ordinary apps cannot generate sensor data to be consumed by other apps.

Comment: You may use the emulator to [simulate the sensor](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator).

Comment: @GenoChen This is not what I want, I want to use sensor from a device to be used for another device, not just for test purpose.